# Pulse LED on button toggle in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, led

I am learning Qt and i came up with an idea to switch on and off an LED with buttons, i got it working but i couldn't figure out how to implement the same with a toggle button. I will be posting the code below, please take a look and let me know how i can implement the above stated behavior.

[image: gif showing the behavior]

**pulseledwidget.h**

```
#ifndef PULSINGLEDWIDGET_H
#define PULSINGLEDWIDGET_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class pulsingLedWidget : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit pulsingLedWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void startPulsing();
    void extinguish();
private:
    QPixmap onPixmap,offPixmap;
    QTimer timer;
    bool state;
};

#endif // PULSINGLEDWIDGET_H
```

**pulseledwidget.cpp**

```
#include "pulsingledwidget.h"

pulsingLedWidget::pulsingLedWidget(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    onPixmap.load(":/ledon.png");
    offPixmap.load(":/ledoff.png");

    state = true;

    setPixmap(offPixmap);
    timer.setInterval(200);
    connect(&timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(startPulsing()));
}

void pulsingLedWidget::startPulsing()
{
    timer.start();
    if(state)
    {
        setPixmap(onPixmap);
        state = false;
    }
    else
    {
        setPixmap(offPixmap);
        state = true;
    }
}

void pulsingLedWidget::extinguish()
{
    timer.stop();
    setPixmap(offPixmap);
}
```

**leddialog.h**

```
#ifndef LEDDIALOG_H
#define LEDDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "pulsingledwidget.h"

class ledDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ledDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QPushButton *onbutton;
    QPushButton *offbutton;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
    pulsingLedWidget *ledwidget;
};

#endif // LEDDIALOG_H
```

**leddialog.cpp**

```
#include "leddialog.h"

ledDialog::ledDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QPushButton *onbutton = new QPushButton("On");
    QPushButton *offbutton = new QPushButton("Off");
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    pulsingLedWidget *ledwidget = new pulsingLedWidget(this);

    ledwidget->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    layout->addWidget(ledwidget);
    layout->addWidget(onbutton);
    layout->addWidget(offbutton);

    resize(150,200);
    connect(onbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),ledwidget,SLOT(startPulsing()));
    connect(offbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),ledwidget,SLOT(extinguish()));

}
```

**What i have tried :**

**leddialog.h**

```
#ifndef LEDDIALOG_H
#define LEDDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "pulsingledwidget.h"

class ledDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ledDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
private slots:
    void makeDecision(bool state);
private:
    QPushButton *onbutton;
    QPushButton *offbutton;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
    pulsingLedWidget *ledwidget;
};

#endif // LEDDIALOG_H
```

**leddialog.cpp**

```
#include "leddialog.h"

ledDialog::ledDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QPushButton *onbutton = new QPushButton("On");
    QPushButton *offbutton = new QPushButton("Off");
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    pulsingLedWidget *ledwidget = new pulsingLedWidget(this);

    ledwidget->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    onbutton->setCheckable(true);

    layout->addWidget(ledwidget);
    layout->addWidget(onbutton);
    layout->addWidget(offbutton);

    resize(150,200);
connect(onbutton,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(makeDecision(bool)));

}

void ledDialog::makeDecision(bool state)
{
    if(state)
    {
        ledwidget->startPulsing();
    }
    else
    {
        ledwidget->extinguish();
    }
}
```

but the above procedure is not working. I tried to run it in debug mode to know the mistake that i have made, it is showing "Segmentation fault" error.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I have used debugger, it is showing a small dialog with "signal received" heading, and has contents which i have no idea.
`Signal name : SIGSEGV`
`Signal meaning : Segmentation fault`

Comment: In your `ledDialog` constructor, you have `pulsingLedWidget *ledwidget = new pulsingLedWidget(this);`. Here you create a new local variable, you're not initializing the member variable. It should be `ledwidget = new pulsingLedWidget(this);`

Comment: @thuga Thankyou, i didn't know how i missed that.

Comment: You missed that because you didn't use the debugger properly. I have no idea what sort of a debugger you used, but any sanely configured debugger will stop right where the code has crashed, you can inspect the variables then. Your downfall is the manual memory management. There's no need to hold any sub-widgets/sub-layouts in `ledDialog` by anything but value. It will be then impossible to commit the mistake you did, plus your code is a bit more efficient, too. Win-win.